# Python: отловить none

Tags: python

Записываю в файл массив таким образом:

```
f.write('[' + str(r[i])[:-2] + '000,' + str(e[i]) + ',' + str(c[i]) + '],')
```

Но если нет значения в массиве, то записывается none. Как записывать 0, а лучше вообще не добавлять строку в массив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что `r` - или кортеж или список.

```
if r[i] != None:
    f.write('[' + str(r[i])[:-2] + '000,' + str(e[i]) + ',' + str(c[i]) + '],')
```

Это должно сработать.

А вообще рассмотрите этот пример:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = [9, 8, 7]
c = [2, 3, 4]

z = zip(a, b, c)

for i1, i2, i3 in z:
    print(i1, i2, i3)
```

Функция `zip` пакует списки и/или кортежи, и Вы можете совершать их обход в одном цикле, не заморачиваясь с ключами. Но обход заканчивается, если один из входящих элементов пройден до конца. Т.е. если в списках по 100 элементов, но в одном из них - 75, то будет 75 проходов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так:

```
from itertools import izip, ifilter
...

for triplet in ifilter(all, izip(r, e, c)):
entry = '[{:.0f}000,{},{}],'.format(*triplet)
f.write(entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно проверить значения во всех трёх массивах, то можно просто:

```
if r[i] and e[i] and c[i]:
    f.write('[' + str(r[i])[:-2] + '000,' + str(e[i]) + ',' + str(c[i]) + '],')
```